# sports scoring in multiple phases in excel

Tags: excel

I have a question about excel.
There is a sports tournament with multiple phases. And the results page looks something like this:

```
rank phase1 phase2
1   TOM     ALBERT
2   MATT    TOM
3   ROBIN   MATT
```

The first place gets 5 points, second 3 and third 1 points.
So the summary I would like to get is like this

```
rank  name  phase1  phase2 total
1    TOM     5       3     8
2    ALBERT  0       5     5
3    MATT    3       1     4
4   ROBIN    1       0     1
```

I cant figure out how to generate it simply, so if I copy-paste the results from phase3 to somewhere in my excel sheet, the summary page would also update.

If you can support me with advice or just a working template, I would be thankful!
Thank you for your time!

Comment: Is there only ever the 4 players?

Comment: oh no. its just an example. there are about 30 players. and everybody wont take part in every phase.  its like 30 players in both phases with 50 unique players total. I just want to know the idea of how this works, so I could customize the details later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done you a basic example below...just list all 50 players in the summary page and copy the formula down as it is - as per the question it only records a value for the top 3 places, hope this helps if not please let me know :)

[Example file here](http://wikisend.com/download/142488/Example.xlsx)

Comment: forgot to add, in the case the players don't score or take part it will still just return 0

Comment: Thank you, I used your solution because you added an easy-to-use template. It works very well!

Comment: Thanks, glad to be of service :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the structure you defined and that when you paste phase 3 it will have its header ("phase3") on the same row as the other results, you could have the following formula on your Table 2:

```
{=SUM(IF(IFERROR(MATCH($B2,INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&CHAR(64+MATCH(C$1,Sheet1!$1:$1,0))&":"&CHAR(64+MATCH(C$1,Sheet1!$1:$1,0))),0)-1,0)={1,2,3},{5,3,1},0))}
```

Note: entered as Array formula: CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER

Formula uses the Table 2 headers ("phase1","phase2", etc.) and the players names to find the results for each phase. It then uses the predefined arrays that determine points given per position. The final sum is to bring the result that are in array (other values in array are 0) into single value.

Total would sum results per player.

Under the rank cells you would place the following formula:

```
=RANK(F2,$F:$F)
```

Which would provide you the rank of each player (Column F containing the totals).

Note that this would not sort your rank automatically but you could easily do this with Sorting or Autofilter. Hope this helps. Cheers.